# Running a global function before the other functions in all the JavaScript pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a fb.js file which is included in all the js files of my app. 
fb.js contains an authenticating function `window.fbAsyncInit` which runs asynchronously fetching the id & other details of a user from Facebook. This data is required by other functions of the page.

The problem I am facing is

A. Right now all the functions are running asynchronously irrespective of their occurrence. I need to run this function before the other functions of the page & wait for the response before running further functions. So that I can use the response of this function in other functions.

B. May be I don't include this authentication function in every page & run just once when the app loads for the first time & pass the data to other pages. Would this be achievable? I am using JQuery.

All the functions of a page excluding `window.fbAsyncInit` are triggered within:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    dummyFunction();
});
```

Occurrence in the page

```
window.fbAsyncInit{}
Other functions within $(document).ready(function() {});
```

A snippet below of the Facebook function

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxx',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.9'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  }
```

Disclaimer: I don't have much experience with JavaScript. I am more of a backend developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to trigger an event to communicate that Facebook initialization has been done.

```
// Write this line just below FB.init function
$(document).trigger('facebookInitialized');
```

And you need to register a listener for this event inside the ready function.

```
$(document).bind('facebookInitialized',function(){
    // Here you can write all the logic to be executed after FB load.
});
```